# Facing issue to add property to object JS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to add property to file object. I am adding property like this (I am using Vue):

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="file" @change="setToUploadStatus" multiple>
```

setToUploadStatus method:

```
setToUploadStatus (event) {
    let files = event.target.files

    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
        let id = this.randomString(10)
        file.id = id
        this.uploadStatus.push({
            id: id,
            name: file.name,
            uploading: false,
            uploaded: false
        })
    }

    this.uploadFile(files)
}
```

uploadFile method:

```
async uploadFile (files) {
    for (const file of files) {
        // Upload file with axios
    }
}
```

randomString method:

```
randomString (length) {
  let text = ''
  let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
  }
  return text
}
```

My problem is it's not adding `id` property always. Sometime it's adding sometime not. Specially when many files are selected. Here is a log https://prnt.sc/kxsqhi

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Converted to a snippet here:

```js
setToUploadStatus(event) {
    let files = event.target.files

    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
        let id = this.randomString(10)
        file.id = id
        this.uploadStatus.push({
          id: id,
          name: file.name,
          uploading: false,
          uploaded: false
        })
      }

      this.uploadFile(files)
    }

    async uploadFile(files) {
      for (const file of files) {
        // Upload file with axios
      }
    }

    randomString(length) {
      let text = ''
      let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
      }
      return text
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="file" @change="setToUploadStatus" multiple>
```

Comment: Please revise to present code without syntax errors, it may be that you did not include all your code by accident.  Where is `event` defined? (in `event.target...`)

Comment: Oh sorry for that. Let me include all code.

Comment: i converted your code to a snippet now you can run that and see that it still has syntax errors.  Note this code does NOT include vue.js either.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Lfwg75r9/14/

Answer (score 0):

First, from the code you've given there is nothing wrong with it. Perhaps the issue is coming from somewhere else.

Second, I see you want to give a unique `id` to every file. Generating a random string is fine, but there is still a possibility that two `random` strings will be the same. So here is a simple way to go about that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    updateFile(event) {
      let files = event.target.files
      let uid = 0;
      Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
        file.id = ++uid;
        console.log(file);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" multiple @input="updateFile" />
</div>
```

This implementation is simple.

Here is the JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/clintonyeb/3qreb1L9/

Comment: Here is an example that after some files it doesn't add id. http://prntscr.com/kxsqhi

Comment: When I run this, they all have id:1

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Please look at my codes again. I have included every code. Maybe I am doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss how is that possible, when I run they all have different ids. :(